# Solve in $\mathbb R$ : $x^4-2x^{3}-3x^{2}+4x+\frac{15}{16}=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Problem :

Solve in $\mathbb R$ :

$x^4-2x^{3}-3x^{2}+4x+\frac{15}{16}=0$

The roots are : (by Wolfram Alpha )

$x_{i}=\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1+\sqrt 2}{2},-\frac{1-\sqrt 2}{2}$

I don't know how to start because in the first place it is not simple to try roots like $\frac{3}{2}$ 
So I need some ideas or hints to factorization this cubic equation

Comment: Once you multiply the equation by $16$, you will recognize that potential roots will be in the form $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ is a factor of $15$ and $q$ is a factor of $16$.

Comment: You could use the rational root theorem to find the possible rational solutions.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AndrewChin can you explain ? More

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). The ratio of the factors of the constant term and leading coefficient will give you all the possible rational solutions, including $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{5}{2}$. Then, you have to test them.

Comment: @KM101  thank you very much

Comment: After you divide by $x-\frac{3}{2}$ and $x-\frac{5}{2}$, you can use [polynomial long division](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/polydiv2.htm) or [synthetic division](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthdiv.htm) to get a quadratic. Then using the quadratic formula, you should be able to find the remaining roots $-\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2}$ and $-\frac{1-\sqrt2}{2}$.

Comment: @TobyMak the roots given in the question do not match the polynomial.

Comment: @will can you try changing the coefficient of $x^1$ to $5$?  I'm wondering if that works but I made a mistake when I tried it.

Comment: @OscarLanzi that way, one rational root 3/2, then a cubic; the roots in the question are close, just some minus signs wrong

Comment: Yup, I ran into the same thing.  So I was not off.  I will now vote to close the question as unclear because of the mismatch.  I will remove the lose vote if the OP can get things corrected.

Comment: OP see Will's and my comments.

Comment: The monic polynomial with those roots is $x^4 - 3 x^3 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{19x}{4} - \frac{15}{16}$. So something is definitely wrong with the question, as others have noted.

Comment: Ah...the roots of the given polynomial are $\frac{-3}{2}, \frac{5}{2}$, and then $\frac12 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac12 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that instead of a polynomial in $x$ we had a polynomial in $2x$.

$$\begin{align}
x^4 - 2x^3-3x^2+4x+\frac{15}{16}&=0\\
16x^4 - 16\cdot2x^3-16\cdot3x^2+16\cdot4x+15&=16\cdot0\\
(2x)^4 - 4(2x)^3-12(2x)^2+32(2x)+15&=0\\
y^4 - 4y^3-12y^2+32y+15&=0\\
\end{align}$$

Where $y=2x$.

Can you take it from here? :)

Comment: The idea is sound in principle, but the polynomial equation is rendered wrong in the question.  It needs to be corrected and then the answer updated.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, I realized that when I entered the LHS into FooPlot.

Answer (score 0):

There's been some discussion about the roots and/or coefficients not being quite right, so I'll colour the suspect-but-irrelevant-to-my-point parts in red. (Well, I do have to assume *one* thing is preserved after as yet unidentified corrections, namely that a substitution I'll mark in blue leads to all coefficients being integers after we've rescaled the constant term.)

If we first rescale so all coefficients are integers, we find powers of $2$ dividing a lot of coefficients. Defining $\color{blue}{y:=2x}$, we want to factorize $y^4\color{red}{-4y^3-12y^2+32y}+15$, and the rational root theorem tells us the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1,\,\pm 3,\,\pm 5,\,\pm 15$. In fact $3,\,5$ work (as requested), so we can take out a factor of $y^2-8y+15$. The ratio is a quadratic $y^2+ky+1$, and the $y^3$ coefficient tells us the value of $k$, and hence the roots $x=\frac{-k\pm\sqrt{k^2-4}}{4}$. As it stands, we get $\color{red}{k=4,\,x=-1\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$.